# MySQL radius search

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geometry, cartesian-coordinates, great-circle

I am making an application with radius search, here is the example I learned from

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql

In my case

I do

SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(-37.814107)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(144.96327999999994)) + sin(radians(-37.814107)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance;

when lat = -37.8141070000, lng = 144.9632800000

SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(-37.814107)) * cos(radians(-37.8141070000)) * cos(radians(144.9632800000) - radians(144.96327999999994)) + sin(radians(-37.814107)) * sin(radians(-37.8141070000)))) AS distance;

MySQL output the distance as NULL, why? Did I do something wrong?

How I fix it? Sorry I am really NOT good at math.

Comment: I think I got the answer, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411836/mysql-bug-trigonometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

You must have a MySql table in your query with lat & lng as fields.
ie

```
SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(-37.814107)) 
       * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(144.96327999999994))
        + sin(radians(-37.814107))
        * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance FROM table;
```

Comment: Hi david, I do have a table, there is a row with lat = -37.8141070000, lng = 144.9632800000.

But mysql is always output the distance as NULL of this row.

Comment: BUT you must have the table name in query.In both your queries there is no database

Comment: Thank you David, I DO know this. Because my queries are very complicated so I simplified my question.